# PHP extension installation on Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, php-extension

I have been trying to install the curl extension using sudo apt-get install php5-curl. But keep getting the below error message

```
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main php5-curl 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.17
404  Not Found 
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security/main php5-curl 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.17
404  Not Found 
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-curl_5.3.2-1ubuntu4.17_amd64.deb  404  Not Found 
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I tried running php -i | grep curl to check if curl is already installed but get got
-bash: php: command not found

I figured i had to install php5-cli extension, an attempt to do that also resulted in the error below

```
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main php5-cli 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.17
404  Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security/main php5-cli 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.17
404  Not Found 
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-cli_5.3.2-1ubuntu4.17_amd64.deb  404  Not Found 
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: as written  try `apt-get update`

Comment: did you try the suggestions?

Comment: Yes i did, got E: The update command takes no arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you ping `security.ubuntu.com`?

If so, try the following sequence:

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5 php5-cli
```

Comment: Thank you, i totally misunderstood apt-get update, thought it was meant to update the individual packages i was trying to install so i ran apt-get update php5-curl, I understand apt-get update now, i have ran it and it now works.

Comment: If you haven't seen this yet, it is a good resource for those starting fresh with `apt-get`: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto